# how to create custom layout page in custom theme

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, custom, page

I want to create a custom page layout in my custom theme.
I have created a custom theme named "ktheme" with a parent theme. I created `cutome_home.xml` in the layout folder but I am just getting a blank home page.

How can I get the header to display on the home page?

Comment: share your theme code here

Comment: Check this one : https://www.rohanhapani.com/add-new-page-layout-option-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 20):

Your question is very brief, it sounds like you're trying to create a new page layout? If that's correct you need to also declare it in `layouts.xml`.

[Official documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-types.html)

### How to Create a Custom Page Layout

**Add your layout**

In this example I'll create a layout named Test Layout, it's the exact same as the one column layout but you can add your own here.

Create this file (changing the name to suit your layout):

```
app/design/frontend/**VENDOR**/**THEME**/Magento_Theme/page_layout/test-layout.xml
```

Content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

My test layout is based off the empty page layout so it's starting from scratch, you can also create a layout based another layout, such as 2columns-left or 3columns. To do that just replace `<update handle="empty"/>` with the layout you wish to use, e.g `<update handle="3columns"/>`

**Inform Magento of your layout**

Create this XML file:

```
app/design/frontend/**VENDOR**/**THEME**/Magento_Theme/layouts.xml
```

This is where you declare your custom layouts, like so.

```
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
    <layout id="test-layout">
        <label translate="true">Test Layout</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

And now we can use our new layout either in the XML or the admin:

[image: Page Layout]

Comment: when i select test layout.. my home page is coming blank...
what i should do to add header in home page..

Comment: You will need to add/edit your layout in the xml file to get it to display what you want, in my example it would be test-layout.xml. If you don't know how to add containers via the XML I suggest reading the documentation - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-types.html. If you still don't understand then if you provide your code we should be able to help further.

Comment: Following your sample I get these error in my system.log https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/99a3dc6b723404cb5c16e0c8305517e4/raw/8d46a81d24a475f2e67dc8f5a6f461f5afaa1af5/system.log

Comment: @Michelangelo - I don't think most those errors are related to this apart from `No element found with ID 'before.body.end'.` Did you copy and paste the code from above? As that error doesn't make sense to me, we haven't told Magento `before.body.end` is an element, it's a block name.

Comment: @Michelangelo You could try the fix mentioned here - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133618/got-error-critical-broken-reference-no-element-found-with-id-checkout-header

Comment: @BenCrook thanks but that solution doesn't work.

Comment: I'd need to see your full code to get an idea of the problem sorry, if you add a question I'll take a look.

Comment: How do you use it in the XML ?

Comment: @maxagaz add `layout="layoutNameHere"` to the `<page>` tag. See http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121034/how-to-change-layout-of-category-list-page-in-magento-2-by-xml for more info

Comment: @BenCrook Thanks! Where can we find the complete list of "handles" for the layout (empty, 2columns-left, 3columns, etc) ?

Comment: @maxagaz The quickest way I've found is to login to the admin and check which layouts are available for CMS pages.

Comment: If you want to view the code for the default page layouts they are located in `magento/module-theme/view/AREA/page_layout` where area is admin/frontend/base. Although this won't contain any extra ones added by any modules or themes.

Comment: So many examples don't mention to put it in the Magento_Theme sub folder of the theme, this is the only and first place I have found this information. Props. This solution works for Magento 2.2

Comment: How to add custom CSS to the `page_layout/test-layout.xml`?