# How to change layout of category list page in magento 2 by xml

Tags: magento2, category, catalog

I want to change layout of category listing page from **2columns-left** to **1column** by **xml**.

for this what i have tried so far.

In `root\magento-ce-2.0.0\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout\catalog_category_view.xml`

I changed

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

to

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

but this is not working, whereas if i change **Page Layout of category** from admin of then changes reflecting but i don't want to make changes from admin i want it from xml.

Can any one please help me for this.

Comment: Any solution for this? I have the same problem.

Comment: Create custom module with sequence or override it in your theme.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

May be other module rewrite that layout please check other module not conflict with it.

It is bad habit to edit core files create module and add file to

**app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml**

add below code to file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer firstly this is my fresh installation and their is no other module in it. and i am making changes in core file for just confirmation once i get working then i will revert all my changes and create my own module. Any ways i have create a module which override  this layout and its working. But why core file not reflecting changes can you please tell me.