# Changing layout of specific page_layout

Tags: magento-2.1, page-layouts

Whenever I want to change the `layout of a CMS page with a specific layout (here: new-layout)`, it changes on `all CMS pages`.

**Vendor/My/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page layout="new-layout" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="page.top">
                <block class="xx\xx\xx" name="test" template="Xx_Xx::test.phtml"/>
            </referenceContainer>
        </body>
    </page>
```

I've only added one page with 'new-layout', but this block gets added on all CMS pages.

Comment: You can add new layout for specific page from the backend  ,like go to that specific page , edit the page , below you will find design section where you can see text box for layout update xml . add your code over there and it will works .

Comment: manthan Dave,please put it as answer

Comment: @ManthanDave I know. But I want to do it this way. We have multiple dev environments, so that would cost more time.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a layout handle for specific CMS pages other than home. cms_index_index.xml or cms_index_index_id_home.xml however none for the other pages it seems.

Comment: AmitBera i guess @harri is trying to do this on another manner ,so lets keep in comment only

Comment: @harri akaik then you need to create custom layout for that specific page and then while creating page you need to choose that layout , hope you understand what i mean , same like 1 column , 1 column left  - create your custom like custom-for-custom-page and assign to that cms page

Comment: Yeah i think i get what you mean you will still have to go to the pages and set in admin however like that, I was more saying that i think your way is the way to go. As there is no specific handle to target a single page unless it's the homepage which I find a bit odd. I think that cake was hoping cmd_page_id_7.xml for example could be used.

Comment: But yeah you mean like this? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117997/how-to-create-custom-layout-page-in-custom-theme so then you just drop down to the page layout within admin?

Comment: That topic explains how to add a page layout. However, when I for example want to add a block to page.top container in default.xml, it gets added to all the page.top containers on all pages. I want to add the block only to the page.top container on the page where the new-layout is selected.

Comment: @harri - Yes exactly that is what i am trying to say by creating custom layout and then assign that layout to custom page where  you need

Comment: @Cake - Then you can define that block to that specific custom layout which you have created , ultimately it will only call when that specific page will be called , Hope you got it