# How to make 4 column layout file in magento

Tags: magento2, layout, frontend, column

I want to make custom layout like 4 column to show on front end.

it gives default
 1 column ,2 columns with right bar,2 columns with right bar and  3 columns.

which types of changes in xml file??

Comment: check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117997/how-to-create-custom-layout-page-in-custom-theme